# Initialize Realm object through Decodable

Tags: swift, realm

This is my code:

```
class A: Object, Decodable{

    let listA = List<Int>()

    required init() {
        self.init()
    }

    required init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema) {
        fatalError("init(realm:schema:) has not been implemented")
    }

    required init(value: Any, schema: RLMSchema) {
        fatalError("init(value:schema:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: CodingKey{}

    public required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init()
    }
}

class B: A{

    let listB = List<Int>()

    private enum CodingKeys: CodingKey{}

        public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            let encoder = try container.superDecoder()
            try super.init(from: encoder)
        }

        required init(value: Any, schema: RLMSchema) {
            fatalError("init(value:schema:) has not been implemented")
        }

        required convenience init() {
            self.init()
        }

        required init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema) {
            fatalError("init(realm:schema:) has not been implemented")
        }
}
```

This is my JSON:

```
{
  "A": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
    "B": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
}
```

How can I initialize object B with all the values from the JSON? Ofcourse, Object A should be initialized as well. I want to do it from the decoder but I got lots of errors in my code.

Because Realm forces initializers to be convenience, I can not call the initializers from another level. How can I change my initializers so that I can initialize class B with a Decoder that goes from subclass (B) all the way to the top class (A)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to use Decodable you need to create lightweight struct DecodedObject and then create Object itself from DecodedObject rewriting properties.

If you want to omit DecodedObject step, you may use ObjectMapper instead of Decodable.